# converting windows studio to not use dll (ftcspi.dll) but use .lib instead

Tags: visual-c++

My visual studio project uses the dll ftcspi.dll to talk over usb/spi to the device.
I want to not to have to use the dll but to use the .lib file instead. 
So in the settings I have FTCSPI.lib added to ProjectSettings->Link->Input.
I have changed the ProjectSettings->Link->General->additionLibraryDirectories t have the location of ftcspi.lib in it.
The exe still doesn't work without having the FTCSPI.dll present.

Answer (score 0):

If the project (**FTCSPI**) is set to compile as a dynamic library, then the .lib you see there is just a file to help the compiler link to that dynamic library (dll).

You would need to compile **FTCSPI** as a static library to achieve what I think you want to achieve.
Configuration Properties -> General -> Configuration type.

Comment: My project is called FixedUpload - the project uses the ftcspi.dll. So you're saying I would need to rebuild ftc spi as a static library then use that in my FixedUpload project ?

Comment: @ade yes. Static libraries are made to be "merged" with whoever uses them. Dynamic libraries hold their own code, and have a small static library (.lib) which only holds the information needed to call the dynamic library's methods, classes, etc..